# Char array and 2D array pointer issues

Tags: c, pointers, command-line-arguments

This is part of an assignment to complete a word search.  I have to use command line arguments to search a predetermined 2D array.  I need to searh only the Horizontal (left to right), Diagnal (top-left to bottom-right), and Vertical (top to bottom).
I'll write the Diag and Vert once I understand the pointer issue better.

I get

```
warning: comparison between pointer and integer
```

This happens at the following if-statement

```
if (argv[count] == g[i][j]){
```

Why do I get the warning and what am I missing in my understanding of pointers that prevents me from doing this.

I've tried different variations of *g and  (int star)g with worse results than just the warning.

I need to have warning free code for turn-in.

Thank You for helping the new people.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define ROW 3
#define COL 4
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

int checkHoriz(char *data, char *data2);

main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int count, i, j, rowValue, colValue;
    char g[ROW][COL] = {{'a','b','c','d'},
                        {'d','c','b','a'},
                        {'x','y','z','d'}};

    count=1;
    if(argc>1){
        for(i=0; i<ROW; i++){
            for(j=0; j<COL; j++){
                if (argv[count] == g[i][j]){
                    rowValue = i;
                    colValue = j;
                    if(checkHoriz(argv[count],g[i][j]) ==TRUE){
                        printf("%s appears horizontally starting @ g[%d]{%d]. \n", argv[count], i,j);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }else{
        printf("No arguments were entered.\n");
    }
}

int checkHoriz(char *data, char *data2){
    int i = 0;
    while (data == data2 && data!=' ' && data2 != '\0'){
        data++;
        data2++;
    }
    if(data2 == '\0'){
        return 1;
    }else{
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can edit your question via [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/9552176/edit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`argv` is an array of strings; a `char**` and `g` is an array of `char` arrays; a `char[][]`.

Therefore, `argv[count]` is of type `char*` (a string), and `g[i][j]` is of type `char`. You're comparing a pointer to a single `char`, an integer type. This is what the warning is telling you.

If you want to search for the `char`s of `g` inside of `argv[count]`, then you're going to need to dereference `argv[count]` one level further, and work with the individual `char`s in the range of `argv[count][0]` to `argv[count][strlen(argv[count]) - 1]`.

Comment: Is argv[count][0] the same as *argv[count]?

Comment: @CodeBlue: Yes they are the same, since the operator `[]` has higher precedence than the operator `*`. Therefore `*argv[count]` is the same as `*(argv[count])`, which refers to the first `char` in the string.